# Signing in an user after a successful external external provider challenge in serverside blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm struggling to configure my serverside web-app to sign-in using an external log-in provider (Discord in this case). I'm using https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers for my oauth providers. It's worth noting that this application is meant to *only* use the discord external provider, there is no regular log-in functionality using username/password.

This is what I have in my Startup.cs's ConfigureServices method to set up authentication, authorization and the discord oauth middleware:

```cs
             services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
             {
                 options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
                 options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                 options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
                 options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
                 options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                 options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                 options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                 options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = false;
             }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddAuthorization();
            services.AddAuthentication().AddDiscord(x =>
            {
                x.ClientId = Configuration["AppId"];
                x.ClientSecret = Configuration["AppSecret"];
                x.Scope.Add("guilds");
                x.Scope.Add("identify");
                x.Validate();
            });
```

and this is what i have in my Configure method

```cs
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            // environment stuff

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });

        }
```

For whatever reason, whenever I perform perform a challenge (which successfully redirects to the discord log-in which then redirects back to /sigin-discord) it is not logging in the user.

This here is my identity controller that handles the login, after the challenge happens, the user is sent to /sigin-discord which then redirects to /sigin in order to either log-in the user or create an account for them if they don't have one yet.

```cs
        [HttpGet("login")]
        public async Task login(string redirectUrl)
        {
            string redirectUri = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback","Identity",new { returnUrl = redirectUrl});

            var properties = await signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync();

            await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(properties.FirstOrDefault().Name, new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUri });
        }

        [HttpGet("signin")]
        public async Task ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? "/";
            var info = await signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                HttpContext.Response.Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            var result = await signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, true);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                HttpContext.Response.Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                var username = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
                if (username != null)
                {
                    var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(info.Principal.Identity.Name);
                    if (user == null)
                    {
                        user = new ApplicationUser(info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name), Convert.ToUInt64(info.ProviderKey));
                        await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
                    }
                    await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
                    await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, true);
                }
                HttpContext.Response.Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
```

However. The signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() always returns null, even though I successfully did the challenge.

Has anyone attempted to use an external sign-in provider with blazor yet? If so, does anyone have an idea why this is not working?